Why are they putting insulating blankets around the new space coronagraph?

As part of the integration process, engineers also ensured blanketing layers were in place to insulate the coronagraph within its place in the Instrument Carrier. The coronagraph is designed to operate at room temperature, so insulation is critical to keep the instrument at the right temperature in the cold vacuum of space.

https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/nasa-successfully-integrates-coronagraph-for-roman-space-telescope/

I assume the coronagraph is heated, so the issue is heat radiating out into space. But the device is already in the best insulation of all, a vacuum.
The insulating blanket can do nothing but conduct heat away from the warm coronagraph. Right?
Wrong. So why?

Heat may transported by convection in a gas or by conduction in a solid or by thermal radiation in a vacuum.

I see that @fyrepenguin has edited your question to supply the source. You should give that user a nice tip o' the hat, Miss Understands.

@fyrepenguin: https://st2.depositphotos.com/1001911/6524/v/950/depositphotos_65242063-stock-illustration-hat-tip-emoticon.jpg

@MissUnderstands there are reasons we ask for certain standards of our askers and our answerers.  You just want to know how stuff happens; we want the result to be useful to others.  Part of that is the simple courtesy of citing sources of quotes, so e.g. in other circumstances it's easier to just say "oh, that source is outdated" or "oh, that's a secondary press-release incorrectly summarizing primary source details" etc etc.

If vacuum is such a great insulator, how come we feel the heat from the Sun ?


But the device is already in the best insulation of all, a vacuum.

Vacuum is the best insulator against heat conduction. It is however the worst insulator against heat radiation.
Without further insulation, sunlight could directly warm the instrument and its own thermal radiation would cool it.

The insulating blanket can do nothing but conduct heat away from the warm coronagraph. Right?

Insulating layers made of e.g. metallized films reflect back most of the radiated heat. Often several layers are used, and there will be vacuum in between them.
This combination is effective at blocking both radiative and conductive heat transfer.

Temperature control in space is a pain. Anything in sunlight near Earth's orbit is going to heat up to ~120 C; anything that's in permanent shadow will eventually radiate away all its heat and get close to 40 Kelvin. Meanwhile, anything that produces heat (CPUs, motors, transmitters) will need some way to reject that heat, or at least spread it around to keep the interior of the craft moderately warm without overheating the equipment that's making heat. And all of this has to happen without the easy temperature moderation of gas convection.
Passive thermal control in space is often in the form of Multi-Layer Insulation (MLI). The inner layers keep the craft from "leaking" infrared radiation into space and thus cooling towards deep-space temperatures by reflecting infrared back into the interior where it can bounce around and keep everything more or less consistently warm. Meanwhile, the exterior reflective layers keep a high-sunlight environment from overheating the interior by keeping most of that solar heating out. Usually this needs to be paired with some kind of active heating and cooling systems to keep the equipment within the proper range, but it all becomes easier with MLI "blankets" to keep the inside and the outside separated. Obviously, the goal is to minimize active thermal control; a well-planned spacecraft may be able to maintain its desired temperature with little or no active control at all, but it all depends on what the equipment needs to do and how often.
